# how to allow special word passing in url?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

i have a appliction where user pass any type of words depend of what they want and website listed them using the word not using ID.

like they pass Blah /Blah then they not work in my application. how i can do something that it's work

like

website.com/user/word/blahblahblah > it's worked 
website.com/user/word/Blah /Blah   > it's not worked

how i can make second work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Server.URLEncode` or `%2F` to represent that character.

Comment: i want a little thing more then i always pass pagenum as last parameter. how i can parse it whenever it's have a pagenum